# Troubleshooting mod_rewrite in a .htacces with a LightSpeed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, litespeed

I have a couple web pages located at these locations:

```
Home Page / Index : www.codeliger.com/index.php?page=home
Education : www.codeliger.com/index.php?page=home&filter=1
Skills: www.codeliger.com/index.php?page=home&filter=2
Projects: www.codeliger.com/index.php?page=home&filter=3
Work Experience: www.codeliger.com/index.php?page=home&filter=4
Contact : www.codeliger.com/index.php?page=contact
```

I am trying to rewrite them to prettier urls:

```
codeliger.com/home
codeliger.com/education
codeliger.com/skills
codeliger.com/projects
codeliger.com/experience
codeliger.com/contact
```

I have confirmed that my htaccess file works and mod-rewrite works to google, but I cannot get my syntax working that was specified in multiple tutorials online.

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule /home /index.php?page=home
  RewriteRule /([a-Z]+) /index.php?page=$1
  RewriteRule /education /index.php?page=home&filter=1
  RewriteRule /skills /index.php?page=home&filter=2
  RewriteRule /projects /index.php?page=home&filter=3
  RewriteRule /experience /index.php?page=home&filter=4
```

How can I fix my syntax to rewrite these pages to prettier urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should probably do is fix your regex. You cannot have a range like `[a-Z]`, you can just do `[a-z]` and use the `[NC]` (no case) flag. Also, you want this rule at the *very end* since it'll match requests for `/projects` which will make it so the rule further down will never get applied. Then, you want to get rid of all your leading slashes. Lastly, you want a boundary for your regex, otherwise it'll match `index.php` and cause another error.

So:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^home /index.php?page=home
  RewriteRule ^education /index.php?page=home&filter=1
  RewriteRule ^skills /index.php?page=home&filter=2
  RewriteRule ^projects /index.php?page=home&filter=3
  RewriteRule ^experience /index.php?page=home&filter=4
  RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```